# How can I reduce the height of box surrounding the `\rule`?

Tags: boxes, rules

I want to make a fancy list of items (based on http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv):

```
\documentclass{article}
                                                                                                                                       
\begin{document}                                                                                                                       
  Title
  \medskip                                                                                                                             
  \hrule

  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}}                                                                                       
    \item[]
    First item
    \smallskip                                                                                                                         
    \hrule
    Comment 1 \hfill Other comment 1                                                                                                   
    \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0em}}                                                                                       
      \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.5em} \vspace{-0.5em}                                                                                     
      \item[] Subitem 1                                                                                                                
    \end{list}
                                                                                                                                       
    \item[]                                                                                                                            
    Second item\\
    \smallskip
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2pt}
    Comment 2 \hfill Other comment 2                                                                                                   
    \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{0em}}                                                                                       
      \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.5em} \vspace{-0.5em}                                                                                     
      \item[] Subitem 2
    \end{list}
  \end{list}
\end{document}
```

Vertically I want the line to look like in the first item (tightly separating two lines), but horizontally I want it to look like in the second item (trimmed to the left margin).

I think the way to go is to limit height of the box surrounding `\rule` (I vave tried to limit width of `\hrule` to `\linewidth` with both `\parabox` and `minipage` - neither worked).  How can I reduce height of that box?